# Using the universal characterisation to derive properties of the quotient group and projection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of some group $G$. If I understand it correctly a group $Q$ and a homomorphism $\pi \colon G \to Q$ are a quotient group of $G$ by $N$ if for any group $H$ and homomorphism $\phi \colon G \to H$ with $N \subseteq \ker(\phi)$ there is a a unique homomorphism $\psi \colon Q \to H$ with $\phi = \psi \circ \pi$.

I was wondering if this characterization is enough to prove that $\ker(\pi)=N$ and $\pi(G)=Q$ or if details of the standard quotient construction in terms of cosets is required to prove these facts.

Comment: This should be enough. Hint: apply the hypothesis for $H=G/N$.

Comment: @Berci Here by $G/N$ do you mean the $Q$ characterized by the universal property or the group of cosets of $N$ for which we know from the construction that the projection is surjective and has the kernel $N$.

Comment: The group of cosets.

Comment: I asked my question because in his category theory book MacLane claims that one can prove the isomorphism theorems using only the universal property but I could not see how to do it without making use of the details of the coset-based construction of $G/N$.

Comment: I don't think it follows from the universal property alone. For example, a category with objects $\{\mathbb Z_6, \mathbb Z_2, 0\}$ (as abelian groups) and all allowed group homomorphisms has $1$ as the quotient of $\mathbb Z_6$ by $\mathbb Z_2$, if I'm not mistaken. I think part of the extra information you need to show that $ker(\pi) = N$ is the existence of any morphism $\phi$ with $ker(\phi)=N$, for then you have $ker(\pi)\subset ker(\phi) = N$....

Comment: Also, I think the definition of quotient requires something like $N\subset ker(\pi)$.  Otherwise $G$ is a perfectly good quotient of $G$ by $N$, with $\pi$ equal to the identity morphism.

Comment: Also, see the related discussion in comments below this MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/a/14524/89079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac Lane doesn't just claim this, he cites the book Algebra by Garret Birkhoff and Saunders Mac Lane (not to be confused with their earlier book A Survey of Modern Algebra) wherein the proofs are carried out (more precisely, pp. 80,81,410-412). The only aspect of normality used in the proofs (at least upon my skimming it) is that normal subgroups are exactly the kernels. In other words, if you replace "normal subgroup" with "kernel of a group homomorphism" in the various statements, the proofs should go through word for word. From this point of view, the coset construction is only a characterization of which subgroups are kernels.

For example, if $N$ is the kernel of $\phi\colon G\to L$, then the universal property of the quotient $G\to G/N$ implies that $N$ is in the kernel of $G/N$ and that we have a factorization $G\to G/N\to L$ of $G\to L$ for a unique $G/N\to L$. But then the kernel of $G\to L$, which is $N$, is contains the kernel of $G/N$, which contains $N$, so $N$ is the kernel of $G/N$.

A more categorical understanding of normality does exist. Namely, a monomorphism $N\hookrightarrow X$ is normal if it is contained in an equivalence class of an equivalence relation on $X$. For more details (though pitched at a somewhat advanced level), see the book From Groups to Categorical Algebra - Introduction to Protomodular and Mal'tsev Categories, by Dominuqe Bourn, or for an even more advanced text, the book Mal'cev, Protomodular, Homological and Semiabelian Categories by Francis Borceux and Dominique Bourn. However, unless the category is exact, normal subgroup are not necessarily kernel, e.g. for Hausdorff topological group kernels are closed normal subgroups.

Comment: I understand your reasoning in the second paragraph, but it assumes that a morphism $\phi \colon G \to L$ with kernel $N$ exists. But how do you show that such a morphism exists?

Comment: You try to construct out of the subgroup an equivalence relation on the group that is stable with respect to the left and right group actions of the group, and then you try to take the quotient by that equivalence relation. The would-be kernel is supposed to consist of group elements equivalent to the identity.

Comment: I know you can show this by taking $L$ to be an explicit construction of the quotient group $G/N$, $\phi$ to be the canonical the projection,and noticing that the kernel is indeed $N$, but that was not the aim my question. I want to know how one can prove the existence of a morphism $\phi : G\to L$ with kernel $N$ *without* any explicit construction; rather only by using the universal property of the quotient.

Comment: @Thomas.M I don't quite underrstand what you want. Consider asking a separate question if you want to discuss further.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with an object $0\in C$ that is both initial and terminal.

Then for any objects $X,Y$ we have a unique morphism $X\to Y$ which factors through $0$.  We call this morphism *trivial*.

Given a morphism $n\colon N \to G$, define its cokernel (if it exists) to be a morphism $\pi\colon G\to Q$ such that $\pi n$ is trivial, and given any morphism $\phi\colon G \to H$, with $\phi n$ trivial, we have a unique morphism $\psi\colon  Q\to H$ with $\psi\circ\pi=\phi$.

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
N & \stackrel n\to & G & \stackrel \pi \to & Q\\
&&& \stackrel \phi\searrow&\downarrow{\tiny \psi}\\
&&&&H
\end{array}$$

Your second question is can we deduce $\pi(G)=Q$.  What does this mean in a general category?  Certainly the codomain of $\pi$ is $Q$.  However you want to say that the image of $\pi$ is the whole of $Q$.  This is equivalent to saying that $\pi$ is a surjective group homomorphism, which is equivalent to saying that $\pi$ is epic.  This last statement is well defined in an arbitrary category, and moreover we can prove that it is true in this case.

Given $f,g\colon Q\to H$ such that $f\pi=g\pi$ we can set $\phi=f\pi=g\pi$.  Then $\phi n$ is trivial, so $\phi$ factors uniquely through $\pi$.  Thus $f=g$.

Now for your first question.  Given $n,\pi$ as before, we say that $n$ is the kernel of $\pi$ precisely when given any map $p\colon P\to G$ with $\pi p$ trivial, we have a unique map $w\colon P\to N$ such that $p=nw$.

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
N & \stackrel n\to & G & \stackrel \pi \to & Q\\
 \uparrow{\tiny w}&\nearrow{\tiny p}\\
P\end{array}$$

Now your first question is can we deduce that $n$ is the kernel of $\pi$, assuming $n$ is normal?

This brings us to the question of what do we mean by $n$ is normal?  A good starting place is that $n$ be monic.  We could try adding that its cokernel exists.  However all of these are true for the inclusion of an arbitrary subgroup in a group.  The cokernel is then the quotient of the normal closure of the subgroup.

What we can do is define $n$ to be normal precisely when its cokernel exists, and $n$ is the kernel of this cokernel.  This works - the normal morphisms in the category of groups are then precisely the inclusions of normal subgroups.

Your first question now becomes rather easy.  We have that the kernel of $\pi$ is $n$, by definition of $n$ being normal.

In summary, in any category with $0$ object, the relevant notions can be defined in a way that precisely agrees with the standard definitions in the category of groups, and with respect to these definitions your two statements can be deduced.

---

An alternative definition of normal is to say that $n$ is normal if it is the kernel of some map.  This also agrees with the usual definition of normal subgroup, in the category of groups.  Proving that $n$ is the kernel of $\pi$ is  still trivial (see comment below by @VladimirSotirov).

Comment: No pullbacks necesary: if $x\to q$ is the cokernel of the kernel $k\to x$ of $x\to y$, then $x\to y$ factors uniquely as $x\to q\to y$ and $k'\to x\to q$ being $0$ implies $l'\to x\to q\to y$ is $0$, so $k'\to x$ factors uniquely as $k'\to k\to x$. Thus $k$ is the kernel of its cokernel $x\to q$. In any case, as I indicated in my answer all of the more general theory requires you work with kernels, and normality is useful only insofar as it is a necessary sufficient for being a kernel, which is sufficient in exact categories.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov You are absolutely right.  I was just about to have a go at this, when I realised it was obvious.  I thought I remembered the corresponding statement in Abelian categories being surprisingly long winded to prove (even with all the extra machinery you have there), but I must have it mixed up with something else.